# Redis Pub/Sub binary

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis. In my app I'm publishing data got from another process. And somewhere else I'm using subscribe to grab incoming data.
But received is malformed.

Publish:

```
myProcess | while read line ; do redis-cli PUBLISH myChannel "$line"; done
```

Subscribe

```
redis-cli SUBSCRIBE myChannel
```

My guess is that Redis does some change to data, so it's malformed.
How to pass and receive raw binary data with no change?

Comment: Binary data doesn't have any concept of *"lines"*, so you can't read lines. And you can't store binary data in a bash variable like `line` because it may contain a null which will be treated as end of the string. I suggest publishing the data from the process directly.

Comment: @Mark Setchell "publishing the data from the process directly", well how can it be? the process pipes data to it's `stdout`. And the process is continuous (Doesn't stop)

Comment: What is the format of the stream? H264? MJPEG?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using your answer in another post about direct piping to Redis publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not near a computer where I can test, but you can't read *"lines"* from a binary stream because they don't have *"lines"* delimited by linefeeds, they just have a stream of binary data. And you can't store binary data that may contain NULs in `bash` variables.

So, completely untested, you'll need to do something like:

```
myProcess | while :; do dd bs=65536 count=1 | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel ; done
```

That will keep reading 64kB chunks and piping them to `redis-cli` without storing in `bash` variables. That's what the `-x` is; it uses its `stdin` (which is the 64kB chunk from `dd`) to supply the data to PUBLISH.

You'll need to optimise the chunk size. Too big and you'll add latency while accumulating data. Too small and you'll overload the i/o with millions of tiny chunks. You'll also need to think about stop conditions and exiting the `while` loop.

---

You may need to surround the `while` statement in curly braces like this:

```
myProcess | { while .... done; }
```

If so, be sure to include **all** the spaces and semicolons shown above.

---

If you have `split` available, this may work:

```
myProcess | split -b 65536 --filter='redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel'
```

Comment: Your first solution works like charm. Thank you. Is `split` available by default in Ubuntu 16.04 and above?

Comment: I think `split` is in `coreutils` package.

Comment: I'm sorry Mark. This might sound stupid. But I'm stuck for many hours. Your answer works. But if first process exits, whole command doesn't exit, or something like that. I don't receive `on exit` event for process in my app.

Comment: I'd need a whole lot more details about your setup amd environment to work out how to quit. One issue that the compression will yield variable length frames depending on the compressibility. Maybe you could prefix the `dd` command with a `timeout` command so that it all times out if `myProcess` stops sending data.

Comment: I've asked it as a question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701817/node-spawn-exit-whole-command-if-first-process-in-a-linux-pipeline-exited]