# Node spawn: Exit whole command if first process in a linux pipeline exited

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, sh

I'm using this command with `spawn` function. It works. But the problem is, if first command exits, `prc.on('exit', () => {...})` won't run.
It's because of either that `sh` script running by `spawn` keeps going, or not getting an exit code. I'm not sure.

```
const command = 'ffmpeg -i [INPUT] -f mpegts pipe: 1 | while :; do dd bs=65536 count=1 2> /dev/null | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel ; done';

const prc = spawn(command, [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });

prc.on('exit', () => {...});//not firing when ffmpeg exits
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75678689/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Use this to take action on normal exit:

```
prc.on('close', (exitCode) => {...});
```

And this to take action on error:

```
prc.on('error', (stdErr) => {...});
```

Comment: `on close` doesn't run either. So I'm sure that while loop keeps going and prevents `sh` to exit.

Comment: Not sure. Did you test running `ffmpeg -i [INPUT] -f mpegts pipe: 1 | while :; do dd bs=65536 count=1 2> /dev/null | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel ; done` in the shell?

Comment: Also, the sub process either exits on close or error, so make sure you have both

Comment: The command is working when there's no errors. I get the result as expected (which is a subscriber receiving data). But when I test it with a dummy input (to make ffmpeg exit), not `on exit` nor `on close` will run. I log `stderr` that's saying ffmpeg exited. Also if I put a dummy `break` for that `while`, I receive exit event.

Comment: How about using two spawns? First one to run ffmpeg, then on close do the second spawn supplying the stdIn from the stdOut of the first one?

Comment: Yeah tried that already. That's OK for 1 or few cases. But in scale, it can kill CPU. So many pipes for 1 core.

Comment: On the other hand it's sequential, so won't use more CPU. If you are concerned about resource usage it would be more efficient to void the shell & pipes and run the commands directly, one after the other

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your point correctly. Isn't it exactly what I'm doing in the question? running one process after another

Comment: With `{ shell: true }` option you are spanning a new shell, which is more expensive than running the `ffmpeg` and other commands directly, while listing the command args as an array. Note that you can't use pipe with that because there is no shell.